# Change max message size in DataServiceContext

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am using `DataServiceContext` to get data from a wcf service which is hosting a dbml. It works fine in general but queries that return large amounts of data (e.g. binary files) create the usual WCF error:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding
```

The problem is I cannot find how to change the message size of the channel.

Here's the code I use to initialise the class:

```
var channel = new RPDataModelDataContext(DataServiceBaseAddress);
channel.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

where `RPDataModelDataContext` is a client proxy class generated with the entityframework

```
public partial class RPDataModelDataContext : 
    global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext
{
    // ...
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found no way to customise the Data channel service client. So I guess that its not possible to.

One has to create a normal wcf client to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having tons of problems with this one as well.  There were three details I was missing.

1. You MUST specify the service `name` exactly.  This should be the fully qualified service name.  (ie. **Namespace.ClassName**)
2. You MUST provide the EXACT `address` of the endpoint. (See code below)

   ```
   <services>
       <!-- The service name below has to be the EXACT Namespace.ClassName of your WCF Data Service-->
       <service name="YourDomainNameHere.YourClassNameHere">
           <!-- The address below must be the EXACT address of your service-->
           <endpoint address ="http://localhost:19766/YourServiceName.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="higherMessageSize" contract ="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler">
           </endpoint>
       </service>
   </services>
   ```
3. The `maxReceivedMessageSize` and the `maxBufferSize` must both be specified

   ```
   <bindings>
       <webHttpBinding>
           <!-- The maxReceivedMessageSize and the maxBufferSize must both be specified as shown below-->
           <binding name="higherMessageSize" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2048000" maxBufferSize="2048000"/>
       </webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This may actually be a service-side issue. You should ensure that **service** configuration file is set as shown at [the answer with most votes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434051/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-data-sent-to-ado-net-data-services) You basically need to change the MaxReceivedMessageSize value to something a little bigger than your largest expected query results size. I've had to set it as high as 2 MB without any issues.